# Reading Gzip File Footer with CURL or WGET

Tags: linux, http, curl, gzip, wget

I have a gzip file in the web server. I want to download the file only if there is enough disk space to decompress the file. Is it possible to know 
 the decompress size before downloading the file?

The decompressed size is encoded in the footer of the gzip file[[1]](https://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Gzip#File_footer). We can extract the decompressed size with the following command

> gzip -l

But, the file need to be downloaded. I want to avoid the file downloading if I could know the decompressed size.

Comment: Not natively. But it should be easy to write this functionality into a server, if that's an option. The server could then add that data to, say, an 'X-Uncompressed-Size' header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hack your way with the [HTTP Range header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests), but it will take many http requests and your server needs to accept the `Range` header.

1. Send a first request with the `HEAD` method, to figure out the total file size `content-length`
2. Send a second request with a `Range` header to get the last 4 bytes of the file. Compute theses bytes to know the file size
3. If you have enough size available on the disk (file-size + uncompressed size), download the full file.

Comment: You don't need to have `file-size` available on disk if you decompress the file dynamically while downloading it, writing only the uncompressed bytes to disk